# Automatic semantic role labeling in FrameNet

Tags: java, nlp, machine-learning

I would like to do automatic semantic role labeling in FrameNet Lexicon using some machine learning methods. Could you please suggest me some java packages most suitable for this project?

Comment: @eowl , thanks for this link.Seems very useful.

Answer (score 6):

[Mate-tools](http://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/) and [SEMAFOR](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/SEMAFOR/) are available and are both written in Java. The latter requires a large memory. The former uses Propbank style, but you can derive the roles.

Comment: Hi Kenston, im really looking into using these packages, but i cant find any documentation on this, i also posted a question on this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937922/automatic-semantic-role-labeling-asrl-in-java-using-frame-net-in-java , is there any change you could share some java code examples?

Comment: For Mate-Tools, you may refer to my comment in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11028562/241379

Comment: Thanks, ill try using the source code, i it OK if ill ask some questions in case thinks go messy?

Comment: Sure, this is encouraged in SO.

Answer (score 5):

University of Illinois (UIUC) has a good [Semantic Role Labeler](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/SRL) which uses PropBank.