# Fast Semantic Role tagging tool in java

Tags: java, nlp

I'm developing an application that requires **FAST** semantic role tagging in java. Can you please suggest me some good tools for that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the ff:

1. [Mate tools](http://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/) (which I'm currently using)
2. [BioKIT](http://nlp.comp.nus.edu.sg/software) - SRL for biomedical text
3. [SEMAFOR](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/SEMAFOR/) - the parser (MST) requires 8GB of RAM
4. [Propbank-Nombank frames](http://nlp.cs.lth.se/software/semantic_parsing:_propbank_nombank_frames/) and [The LTH System for Frame-Semantic Structure Extraction](http://nlp.cs.lth.se/software/semantic_parsing:_framenet_frames/)
    may be related to Mate tools
5. [ClearNLP](http://clearnlp.wikispaces.com/)
6. [CogCompNLP pipeline](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/pipeline): multiple versions of SRL (verb, preposition, comma, noun)

I'm not quite sure when it comes to speed, but Mate tools is not really that slow. They are all written in Java.

Comment: ,Can u share some guideline to use Mate-Tool ,i am not able to understand input data format

Comment: You may check https://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/source/browse/trunk/srl/src/se/lth/cs/srl/CompletePipeline.java but somehow it follows the CONLL 09 format (https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/conll2009-st/task-description.html)

Comment: i got data in CONLL-09 format but now how to SRL,also this SRL is only Research use not Commercial use

Comment: and importent i want to run SRL on windows or using java API

Comment: Do check the sample codes in their Google code. Consider exploring is2.io.CONLLReader09 class which returns SentenceData09 objects. Then you can do something like semanticRoleLabeler.parseSentence(new Sentence(sentenceData09 ));

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to call C code from your Java program, then Senna is probably the fastest Semantic Role Labeling software, and it works pretty well.  It uses PropBank.  It comes with binaries for Windows, Linux & OSX.