# Automatic semantic role labeling (ASRL) in Java (using Frame net in Java)

Tags: java, nlp

I'm looking for a long time to create ASRL analysis in Java, and unfortunately the web offers very little support, it seems like all of the other SO questions relate to "which tools to use", but not to "how to use them".

I want to create (preferably in java) something exactly like this : http://demo.ark.cs.cmu.edu/parse
,an algorithm that has sentences as input, and frames as output.

I downloaded the related Jar files of `mate tools` https://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/downloads/list and 
SEMAFOR http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/SEMAFOR/, but from here I'm stuck, i couldn't find any way of creating java code that does that.

Does any of you guys have examples of Java code (`SEMAFOR` or `Mate tools`) that demonstrates how to convert a sentence (or any text input) into frame elements?

ill appreciate any help on that.

Comment: What you're asking for is still to vague. SEMAFOR (for example) uses it's own methods and processes to perform input text into frames. There isn't snippet of code where you can identify it clearly. It's a pipeline system that has subsystems which work together to produce the results. And I'll say that it's very complex. I suggest you read the paper written about the system (http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/COLI_a_00163). You'll then have a better idea of how the system works. More specifically, read sections 4-6.

Comment: And I'll also say that SEMAFOR can't work by itself, it has other systems that it utilizes, such as the MST parser, probably the FrameViz visualization tool and maybe others.

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might help you.Just go to this link http://code.google.com/p/semafor-semantic-parser/ and browse through the sources.You'll get a lot of java codes on semantic parsing which is used in semafor.You'll also get framenet demo in this chunk of codes.

Comment: Links to relevant content are welcome, but please quote the relevant text since the content on external sites can change or disappear.  Specifically, your answer would be improved if you included inside your answer what the OP asked for: *examples of Java code ... that demonstrates how to convert a sentence (or any text input) into frame elements*

Comment: Thanks for the link, but what I'm really looking for is Java source code example, which doesn't seems to be anywhere, even in that link.

Comment: Did you use the code?, can you show me an example?, id love to understand how it works